# Como fazer a pagina esperar um pop-up?

Tags: javascript

Criei um método para chamar uma pop-up para validar um evento, mas esse evento acontece junto com a validação.

A pop-up aparece e o evento dispara. como faço para o evento esperar a pop-up?

```
if(self.Cookie("my_coocke") == undefined){
    self.OpenConfigurationDialog();
    event();
```

Comment: [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) não soluciona o teu problema?

Answer (score 0):

Cara, tem duas formas de resolver isso, ou você usa a função timeout do Javascript ou você usa o Sleep do PHP, fora o usleep() que Atrasa a execução em milionésimos de segundo.

### Ex Javascript:

```
setTimeout(function() { console.log("setTimeout: Ja passou 1 segundo!"); }, 1000);
setInterval(function() { console.log("setInterval: Ja passou 1 segundo!"); }, 1000);
```

O que o código imprime na tela:

```
setTimeout: Ja passou 1 segundo!
setInterval: Ja passou 1 segundo!
setInterval: Ja passou 1 segundo!
setInterval: Ja passou 1 segundo!
setInterval: Ja passou 1 segundo!
...
```

### Aprofundando:

```
var recursiva = function () {
    console.log("Se passaram 1 segundo!");
    setTimeout(recursiva,1000);
}
recursiva();
```

### Ex Sleep PHP

int sleep ( int $seconds )

### Visão próxima de codificação

```
<?php
// Hora atual
echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";

// Dorme por 10 segundos
sleep(10);

// Acorde!
echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";
?>
```